# Unable to click a value from a sub list of the main list using mouse over action of selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, mouseover, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to automate a scenario where I can select a value from a sub-menu present under main menu.

Below is the application url:

http://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/Home.aspx

Its a mouser over functionality and tried to automate the Tab (**Plan your travel-> Flights -> Book Online**) with the below code but not working:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PlanYourTravel']/span/b"));
WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lnkThirdLevel58']"));
WebElement we2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ddsubSubmenu58']/li[1]/a"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);

    builder.moveToElement(we).perform();

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(we1));
    builder.moveToElement(we1).perform();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(we2));       
    builder.moveToElement(we2).click().perform();
```

I am getting the element not visible issue. Quick help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with below code to click on "Book Online" and its working fine

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/Home.aspx");

    Actions actObj = new Actions(driver);

    //actObj.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Plan Your Travel']"))

    actObj.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='PlanYourTravel']/span/b"))).perform();

    actObj.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='Flights']/a"))).perform();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Book Online']")).click();
```